# JavaScript Array Command History

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm writing a very simple terminal emulator(ish) app and I'm trying to build the functionality where `up-arrow` loads the previous command into the input. I'm close with what I have so far but I'm missing something in my math and it's not working correctly...

```
command_history = {};
command_counter = -1;
history_counter = -1;

$('#term-command').keydown(function(e){
    code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    // Enter key - fire command
    if(code == 13){
        var command = $(this).val();
        command_history[command_counter++] = command;
        history_counter = command_counter;
        alert('Run Command: '+command); 
        $(this).val('').focus(); 
    // Up arrow - traverse history
    }else if(code == 38){
        if(history_counter>=0){
            $(this).val(command_history[history_counter--]);
        }
    }
});
```

...where `#term-command` is my input.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  In what way does it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the issue is that you defined `command_history` as an object `{}` instead of an array `[]`, since you are using it as an array.

Also, I think you want to pre decrement with `--history_counter`

see this working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5DZxs/1/

So your javascript looks like:

```
command_history = []; //<-- Change here
command_counter = -1;
history_counter = -1;

$('#term-command').keydown(function(e){
    code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    // Enter key - fire command
    if(code == 13){
        var command = $(this).val();
        command_history[command_counter++] = command;
        history_counter = command_counter;
        alert('Run Command: '+command); 
        $(this).val('').focus(); 
    // Up arrow - traverse history
    }else if(code == 38){
        if(history_counter>=0){
            $(this).val(command_history[--history_counter]); //<-- Change here
        }
    }
});​
```

Comment: Perfect! Proof that late-night coding leads to stupid mistakes. Thanks!

Comment: If I try to add the down arrow support it jumps to the top of the list (figuratively speaking):  `}else if(code == 40){
            if(history_counter<=command_counter){
                $(this).val(command_history[history_counter++]);
            }
        }` Any ideas?

Comment: I also added a check to ensure that commands aren't blank http://jsfiddle.net/5DZxs/3/

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you are trying to access an array index of -1

```
command_history[command_counter++] = command;
```

command_counter = -1 at first - try initializing it to 0 or use the pre increment(++command_counter) if it existing in javascript.  Also declare command_history as an array.
changes I would make:

```
command_counter = 0;
```

and

```
command_history = [];
```

command history is an array -

Answer (score 0):

Change statement

```
command_history[command_counter++] = command;
```

to

```
command_history[++command_counter] = command;
```

and make your command_history variable as an array like `command_history = [];`

It will solve your issue